# css background image does not appear to create icon beside link

Tags: css, hyperlink, background-image

I've created a horizontal menu using **css**, **ul**, and **li**. Also I would like to show an icon beside each link. But what I've wrote for this does not work.
**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu2ul">
    <li id="general"><a href="g">General Information</a></li>
    <li id="technical"><a href="t">Technical Information</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#general {
    background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519899-175_Information-16.png') left center no-repeat;
}

#menu2ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0
}

#menu2ul li {
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    border-left:1px solid #A3D26F;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:0px
}

#menu2ul li a {
    padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#8CC637;
    min-width:100px;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Please check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sj3X/).
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Covered up by your background colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `#general` to `#general a`

```
#general a{
    background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519899-175_Information-16.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

in other case the image will be behind the background of anchor tag

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/6sj3X/1/)

If you want the icon for all list item then use

```
#menu2ul a{
    background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519899-175_Information-16.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/6sj3X/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519899-   175_Information-16.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Check this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/829TE/

Answer (score 0):

Your id="general" is on the list item, not the inner anchor tag.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5xJX/)

One solution:

page:

```
<ul id="menu2ul">
    <li><a href="g" class="infolink">General Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="t" class="infolink">Technical Information</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.infolink {
    background:url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519899-175_Information-16.png') left center no-repeat;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
}
```